# Force a lightning tab to load without clicking it

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-events

I need to load a lightning tab with in a lightning tab set without having to click on the tab itself.  The reason for this is so I can send an event to the child component (inside the tab) without the user having to first click the new tab to load it.

Sample Code

```
<aura:component>
 <aura:attribute name="selTabId" type="string" default="1" />

    <lightning:tabset aura:id='tabs' selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}">
      <lightning:tab label="Item One" id='1'>
        <c:InitialComponent aura:id="child1"/>
      </lightning:tab>
      <lightning:tab label="Item Two" id='2'>
         <c:ThisComponentNeedsToLoad aura:id="child2"/>
      </lightning:tab>
  </lightning:tabset>
```

So how would I go about getting c:ThisComponentNeedsToLoad without actually clicking on the tab?

I feel like it needs some sort of forced Init function or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my phrasing on the question was off.  What I was trying to do was send data to a lighting component that was nested in a lightning:tabset without the component being clicked on (meaning that it is not initialized) (init will only fire if the component is viewed).  The way this was accomplished was to dynamically create and initialize the component.

```
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.getTabs}">click</lightning:button>
    <lightning:tabset aura:id='tabs' selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}">
    <lightning:tab label="Item One" id='1'>
        <c:Case_InsitutionalCoding aura:id="child1"/>
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab label="Item Two" id='2'>
         <c:Case_Test_Comp_Wrapper1 aura:id="child2" />
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab label="Item Three" id='3' aura:id="ModalDialogPlaceholder">
        Three Content !
    </lightning:tab>
 </lightning:tabset>
```

The problem I was having was I needed to put the aura:id in the lightning:tab rather than the space under it (where 'Three Content !' is).

Then the component can be initialized with `$A.createComponent ()` like in the example here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Answer (score 0):

For now, it's not possible to force an init (unless you force `selectedTabId` to go to that tab first, then your desired tab second).

You could have the child component pull from the parent in its own `init` or using an `attribute` which is stored on the parent and bound with `!` on the child so it propagates to the child once initialized:

```
<aura:attribute name="selTabId" type="string" default="1"/>
<aura:attribute name="parentData" type="Object"/>

<lightning:tabset aura:id='tabs' selectedTabId="{!v.selTabId}">
  <lightning:tab label="Item One" id='1'>
    <c:InitialComponent aura:id="child1"/>
  </lightning:tab>
  <lightning:tab label="Item Two" id='2'>
    <c:ThisComponentNeedsToLoad aura:id="child2" parentData="{! v.parentData }"/>
  </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```

FYI, if it wasn't obvious, don't send an event. Store the event payload on the parent waiting for the child to grab.

Comment: I think this still requires me to actually click on the second tab (Item two) for it to load

Comment: Sure, but it's out of view so why does it need anything? This is the same behavior as the default tab component on a record flexipage. Component in a tab doesn't get created until the tab is selected.

Comment: Yeah but my problem is, I need to update fields on the component without viewing it.  Another component in the page with a different parent component is sending it an event

Comment: I think this is now a state management problem rather than tab problem. If your recordstate is being updated out of the child component view, the child should grab the recordstate from somewhere agnostic - not through an event right? It sounds like you need a cache of some kind (lightning data service...)

Answer (score 0):

The way I am understanding this is that `c:ThisComponentNeedsToLoad` has a method that needs to be invoked from within a method of `c:InitialComponent`. If that is correct, see if below helps? The idea is that the 'common' logic be put in a 3rd dedicated component/method and call it (on demand) from the individual init methods in both components. The fact that your components are housed in tabs suggests that plucking out common logic to put in `loader.cmp` is possible.

> Loader.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:method name="load" action="{!c.load}"/>
</aura:component>
```

> Loader.cmp ControllerJS

```
({
    load : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert("3 - In Loader.cmp ControllerJS");
        //Implement common tab-init logic here
    }
})
```

> InitialComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component>
    <c:Loader aura:id="Loader"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit1}"/>
    <div class="slds-p-around_x-large slds-text-heading_large">
        1 - This is InitialComponent!
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

> InitialComponent.cmp ControllerJS

```
({
    doInit1 : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Initialize other InitialComponent stuff here
        alert("1 - In InitialComponent.cmp ControllerJS");
        var loader = component.find("Loader");
        loader.load();
    }
})
```

> ThisComponentNeedsToLoad.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <c:Loader aura:id="Loader"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit2}"/>
    <div class="slds-p-around_x-large slds-text-heading_large">
        2 - This is ThisComponentNeedsToLoad!
    </div>    
</aura:component>
```

> ThisComponentNeedsToLoad.cmp ControllerJS

```
({
    doInit2 : function(component, event, helper) {
        //Initialize other ThisComponentNeedsToLoad stuff here
        alert("2 - In ThisComponentNeedsToLoad.cmp ControllerJS");
        var loader = component.find("Loader");
        loader.load();
    }
})
```